# Enviar datos de un formulario en la misma pagina

Tags: php, mysql

Me pregunto si es posible mandar datos de un formulario en la misma página teninedo todo el código. Por separado me funciona perfectamente, pero lo que necesito es que los datos se manden en el mismo archivo y se refresque.

Dejo aquí mi código.

```
<?php 

    //Recojo datos del formulario
    $id = $_POST['intro']; 
    $dato = $_POST['datonuevo'];

    //Consulta para actualizar los datos    
    $sql1 = "UPDATE dimension_intro SET text_work='$dato' WHERE id = '$id'";

    if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
        echo "Actualizacion realizada con exito";
    } else {
        echo "Error al actualizar: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $datosantiguos="SELECT id, text_work FROM dimension_intro ORDER BY id";//consulta datos antiguos
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $datosantiguos);//ejecuto la consulta
?>

<select name="intro">

    <?php
    //recorro los datos antiguos
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["text_work"].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
<br>Nueva intro<br>
<input type="text" name="datonuevo"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Actualizar" ><br> <!-- Aqui tenias mal escrito submit jaja -->
</form>

<?php
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Hola... claro que si se puede pero es mala practica, solo en el formulario en el action apuntale al mismo archivo y validas los campos con un isset si vienen datos por post

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo probare y te digo, tambien otra opcion es usarlo en otro archivo pero que no me lleve a el, simplemente que ejecute el codigo en el.

Comment: Claro que si, en otro archivo puedes crear una clase y creas una función que sea guardar los datos, y en el archivo donde tienes el formulario instancias la clase y llamas la función y le mandas los parámetros,  ya seria como mas ordenado..

Comment: Podrias ponerme un ejemplo si no es muchas molestia? No se como hacer eso <3